# Issue with circleci and heroku with react app

Tags: heroku, circleci, circleci-2.0

My CI/CD is: git > cicleci > heroku

I'm using circleci's suggested configuration (attached below)

I have the proper environment variable in circleci.

The first part is working well, however, when I deploy to heroku I can see warnings from devs dependencies like:

`./src/hooks/myHook.js
  Line 11:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'x'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

which makes me think that React dev is running.

Can anyone help me?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    ...
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:trusty
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Deploy Master to Heroku
          command: |
            git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are already but I highly recommend using this Heroku buildpack rather than the standard Heroku Node buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack. This buildpack starts in production by default.

In Heroku go to settings > Buildpacks and click on the Add buildpack, then enter the following url: `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git` and save.

However if there is a hook error as above I would fix that issue by adding it into the dependency array in the hook.